# Admin menu in Impresspages

Tags: php, menu, admin, impresspages

I just installed Impresspages for a client and I really like it.

I guess my client will also like it but I'd like him not to be able to change the zone or some other features in the admin menu.

Is there a way to create group of users and limit access to some functions only? I saw the multisite plugin, but I don't know if it can work. Or maybe trick the code but it seems the admin menu is protected.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can restrict some permissions to the user. Go to `System -> Administrators`, create a new user and remove `Super admin` permission to that user. Then add only those permissions that you like your client to have.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not see it.
Thanks for your time!